# One Corollary of the Kolmogorov Zero-One Law

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Here is an application of the Kolmogorov Zero-One Law given in my textbook (a probability path by Resnick page 107-108). It states that the random variables $\limsup_n X_n$ and $\liminf_n X_n$ are constant with probability 1 due to the law mentioned before. What I do not understand here is that the law only states that these two events should have probability 0 or 1. Could anyone clarify this, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

1. Show that for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ the events $$\left\{ \limsup_n X_n \leq c \right\}, \qquad \quad \left\{\liminf_n X_n \leq c \right\}$$ are tail events.
2. Show that whenever the cumulative distribution function $F_X$ of a random variable $X$ satisfies $F_X \in \{0,1\}$, then $X$ is constant. To this end, use the monotonicity of $F_X$.
3. Apply 2. to $X= \limsup_n X_n$ and $X = \liminf_n X_n$.

Comment: I know that. Given that is true, the theorem only states that the probability of either events is 0 or 1. My question is why it must be 1 in this case.

Comment: @20824 I have added some more hints.

Comment: I got it. Thank you .